# Bibliography/images invading the bottom margin when using quarto extension for elsevier https://github.com/quarto-journals/elsevier)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto, bibliography

I am writting a manuscript using quarto journal template (elsevier: https://github.com/quarto-journals/elsevier). After rendering, the bibliography goes over the bottom margin until the end of the page, gets cut and continues in the next page after top margin.
Same happens with images. How can I stop that?

bibliography:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnO2T.png)
images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51mua.png)

Here is the code

```
---
title: --
framework
author:
  - name: --
    email: --
    affiliations: 
        - id:--
          name: --
          department: --
          address: 1st
          city: 00
          state: 00
          postal-code:00
    attributes:
        corresponding: true
abstract: |
  This is the abstract. 
keywords: 
  - keyword1
  - keyword2
date: last-modified
bibliography: bibliography.bib
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    journal:
      name: Journal Name
      formatting: preprint
      model: 3p
      cite-style: authoryear
    fig-pos: "ht"
editor: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---
```

Code for the images:

```
{r fig_2}
#| label: fig_2
#| fig-cap: A meaningless scatterplot
#| fig-subcap:
#| - "some caption a"
#| - "some caption b"
#| fig-width: 7
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-align: center
#| out-width: 60%
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| column: body
#| warning: False
#| echo: False
...
```

I tried adding

```
references: 
    location: document
```

into the editor block, didnt solve it.
I tried adding `# column: body` into the r code for the plot, didn't solve it.
I changed `fig-pos:"H"` to `fig-pos:"ht"` and also didn't solve it.